# Interrupt equal periods at the end of the month

Tags: oracle, dayofmonth

Oracle DB: [SQL_FIDDLE](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/1b7c8b/1)

It's about counting and the beginning of weekly periods:

Table_1 lists the plan and it's start date.

Table_2 lists periods and the corrseponding Plan from Table_1.

The select

```
select 
t2.PERIOD
 ,'WEEK_NUMBER ' || to_char(t1.START_DATE +((t2.PERIOD-1) * 7), 'iw') Week
,to_char(t1.START_DATE + ((t2.PERIOD-1) * 7), 'YYYY-MM-DD') Period_Start
from TABLE_1 t1
join
TABLE_2 t2
on t1.PLAN = t2.PLAN
```

prints the following:

```
+--------+----------------+--------------+
| PERIOD |      WEEK      | PERIOD_START |
+--------+----------------+--------------+
|      1 | WEEK_NUMBER 18 | 2020-05-01   |
|      2 | WEEK_NUMBER 19 | 2020-05-08   |
|      3 | WEEK_NUMBER 20 | 2020-05-15   |
|      4 | WEEK_NUMBER 21 | 2020-05-22   |
|      5 | WEEK_NUMBER 22 | 2020-05-29   |
|      6 | WEEK_NUMBER 23 | 2020-06-05   |
|      7 | WEEK_NUMBER 24 | 2020-06-12   |
|      8 | WEEK_NUMBER 25 | 2020-06-19   |
+--------+----------------+--------------+
```

Question:
Each period should have 7 days except for periods with a month break. If a period includes a month break, it should go to the last day of the month, and the rest should be continued as a new period in the next month. The Week Number and Period Number should be adjusted.

Example:

```
+--------+----------------+--------------+
| PERIOD |      WEEK      | PERIOD_START |
+--------+----------------+--------------+
|      1 | WEEK_NUMBER 18 | 2020-05-01   |
|      2 | WEEK_NUMBER 19 | 2020-05-08   |
|      3 | WEEK_NUMBER 20 | 2020-05-15   |
|      4 | WEEK_NUMBER 21 | 2020-05-22   |
|      5 | WEEK_NUMBER 22 | 2020-05-29   |< --- period part before new month
|      6 | WEEK_NUMBER 23 | 2020-06-01   |< --- period part after new month
|      7 | WEEK_NUMBER 23 | 2020-06-05   |
|      8 | WEEK_NUMBER 24 | 2020-06-12   |
|      9 | WEEK_NUMBER 25 | 2020-06-19   |
+--------+----------------+--------------+
```

Which procedure is recommended here?

I added another [SQL_FIDDLE](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/55bb8/1) with adional Periods:

```
+--------+----------------+--------------+
| PERIOD |      WEEK      | PERIOD_START |
+--------+----------------+--------------+
|      1 | WEEK_NUMBER 23 | 2020-06-01   |
|      2 | WEEK_NUMBER 24 | 2020-06-08   |
|      3 | WEEK_NUMBER 25 | 2020-06-15   |
|      4 | WEEK_NUMBER 26 | 2020-06-22   |
|      5 | WEEK_NUMBER 22 | 2020-05-29   |< --- period part before new month
|      6 | WEEK_NUMBER 23 | 2020-06-01   |< --- period part after new month (Week_Number has changed)
|      6 | WEEK_NUMBER 28 | 2020-07-06   |
|      7 | WEEK_NUMBER 29 | 2020-07-13   |
|      8 | WEEK_NUMBER 30 | 2020-07-20   |
|      9 | WEEK_NUMBER 31 | 2020-07-27   |< --- period part before new month
|     10 | WEEK_NUMBER 31 | 2020-08-01   |< --- period part afternew month (Week_Number has not changed)
|     11 | WEEK_NUMBER 32 | 2020-08-03   |
|     12 | WEEK_NUMBER 33 | 2020-08-10   |
|     13 | WEEK_NUMBER 34 | 2020-08-17   |
|     14 | WEEK_NUMBER 35 | 2020-08-24   |
|     15 | WEEK_NUMBER 36 | 2020-08-31   |< --- period part before new month
|     16 | WEEK_NUMBER 36 | 2020-09-01   |< --- period part before new month (Week_Number has not changed)
|     15 | WEEK_NUMBER 37 | 2020-09-07   | 
|     16 | WEEK_NUMBER 38 | 2020-09-14   |
+--------+----------------+--------------+
```

Comment: some sample data and and a sample table would help here in addition to what you have above.

Comment: I added another SQL-FIDDLE with more data

Comment: What's the WEEK_NUMBER? Where does it come from / how is it related to the inputs?

Comment: The week number is the calendar week number calculated from Startdate and Period. I actually thought that this would make the example more understandable.

Comment: Calculated, how? Note that if we use your definition of "period", it is possible for different days in the same "period" to be in different ISO weeks. So, what do you mean?

Comment: There can be different Period_Start Days within the same ISO Week, which I compute with  'to_char(t1.START_DATE +((t2.PERIOD-1) * 7), 'iw') Week'. So the Startdate of given Period is withn a certain ISO Week.  It is not unlikely that I am missing something crucial here. Thanks for your answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can compute the "period" number with a recursive query, as follows.

As expressed in the comments under your question, I don't quite understand what you mean with the "week" column (and I suspect it's possible that your definition is actually inconsistent - left to you to clarify).

```
with
  r (plan, period, max_periods, start_date) as (
    select  plan, 1, max_periods, start_date
      from  table_1
    union all
    select  plan, period + 1, max_periods,
            least(start_date + 7, add_months(trunc(start_date, 'mm'), 1))
      from  r
      where period < max_periods
  )
select plan, period, start_date
from   r
;

PLAN     PERIOD START_DATE
---- ---------- ----------
A             1 2020-05-01
A             2 2020-05-08
A             3 2020-05-15
A             4 2020-05-22
A             5 2020-05-29
A             6 2020-06-01
A             7 2020-06-08
A             8 2020-06-15
A             9 2020-06-22
A            10 2020-06-29
A            11 2020-07-01
A            12 2020-07-08
```

This is based on the max periods from TABLE_1, and I am not using TABLE_2 at all. You can join the two tables after you generate this result set from TABLE_1 alone, or adapt the approach as needed.

Comment: did you try this in the fiddle example? I get an error: ORA-00904: "MAX_PERIODS": invalid identifier

Comment: @PeterS - when I posted my answer, I tested on my machine. I just tested it on sqlfiddle right now, and it works perfectly. I see you posted a second sqlfiddle example; I tried it only on your original one. Your second example no longer has the MAX_PERIODS column in the first table - what's up with that? Does your table have that column, or not?