# JOIN (VALUES (0),(1),(2),(3),...... ON Logic

Tags: sql-server, join

SQL-SERVER 2017

[SQL-FIDDLE](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/ed4e1f/1)

DB-CODE:

```
CREATE TABLE [TABLE_1] (
PLAN_NR decimal(28,6) NULL,
START_DATE datetime  NULL);

INSERT INTO TABLE_1
(PLAN_NR,START_DATE)
VALUES
(1,'2020-05-01'),
(2,'2020-08-01');
```

My question is about the Syntax of the following Select:

```
WITH Dates AS(
SELECT T1.PLAN_NR,
       V.I+1 AS PERIOD_NR,
       DATEADD(DAY, 7*V.I, T1.START_DATE) AS START_DATE,
       LEAD(DATEADD(DAY, 7*V.I, T1.START_DATE)) OVER (PARTITION BY PLAN_NR ORDER BY V.I) AS END_DATE
FROM dbo.TABLE_1 T1
 ------------------------------------------------
  --> JOIN (VALUES(0),(1),(2),(3),(4),(5),(6),(7),(8),(9),(10)) V(I) ON 1000 >= V.I) <-- THIS LINE
 ------------------------------------------------
SELECT D.PLAN_NR,
   D.PERIOD_NR,
   V.START_DATE
FROM Dates D
 CROSS APPLY (VALUES(START_DATE),(CASE WHEN MONTH(START_DATE) != MONTH(END_DATE) THEN 
DATEADD(MONTH,DATEDIFF(MONTH,0,END_DATE),0) END)) V(START_DATE)
WHERE V.START_DATE IS NOT NULL
```

What is the logic to extend the values here to e.g. 1000?
Do I have to write out VALUES(0),(1),(2),(3),(4),(5),(6),(7),(8),(9),(10)......(1000)?

Edit:

I got the code mentioned here from [Larnu](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2029983/larnu) answer to another question:
[here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65540537/calculate-start-date-of-almost-equal-periods/65540632#65540632).

Comment: Does this answer your question? [SQL Select 'n' records without a Table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6533524/sql-select-n-records-without-a-table)

Comment: FYI, from my [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65540632/2029983) you've taken this from, I even cite an article to show you how to do what you're asking: *"If it's larger than 10, like* way *larger, then you can use an inline one, using CTEs (see [Tally Tables in T-SQL](https://www.sqlservercentral.com/blogs/tally-tables-in-t-sql))."*

Comment: Thanks and I hope it doesn't seem lazy here to turn your code into this syntax question.I would have been interested in increasing the syntax here to 20, 30, 40 etc values.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would create an extended tally:

```sql
WITH N AS(
    SELECT N
    FROM (VALUES(NULL),(NULL),(NULL),(NULL),(NULL),(NULL),(NULL),(NULL),(NULL),(NULL))N(N)),
Tally AS
    (SELECT 0 AS I
     UNION ALL
     SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY (SELECT NULL)) AS I
     FROM N N1,
          N N2,
          N N3),
Dates AS
    (SELECT T1.PLAN_NR,
            T.I + 1 AS PERIOD_NR,
            DATEADD(DAY, 7 * T.I, T1.START_DATE) AS START_DATE,
            LEAD(DATEADD(DAY, 7 * T.I, T1.START_DATE)) OVER (PARTITION BY PLAN_NR ORDER BY T.I) AS END_DATE
     FROM dbo.TABLE_1 T1
          CROSS JOIN Tally T)
SELECT D.PLAN_NR,
       D.PERIOD_NR,
       V.START_DATE
FROM Dates D
     CROSS APPLY (VALUES (START_DATE),
                         (CASE
                               WHEN MONTH(START_DATE) != MONTH(END_DATE) THEN DATEADD(MONTH, DATEDIFF(MONTH, 0, END_DATE), 0)
                          END)) V (START_DATE)
WHERE V.START_DATE IS NOT NULL;
```

Comment: Thx I tried this in the Fiddel but got an "The multi-part identifier "V.I" could not be bound."

Comment: Just need to change `V.I` to `T.I` @PeterS (a minor oversight). I'll fix, but a simple change you could do too (and the error was quite apparent on the problem).

Comment: And fixed, @PeterS .

Answer (score 1):

You don't need, you can have a CTE to generate the number and join in like following.

```
WITH cteNum
AS (
    SELECT 1 AS I
    
    UNION ALL
    
    SELECT I + 1
    FROM cteNum
    WHERE I + 1 <= 1000
    )
```

Your final query will look like

```
with cteNum as 
(
 select 1 as I
 union all 
 select I +1 from cteNum
 where I + 1<=1000
), Dates AS(
    SELECT T1.PLAN_NR,
           V.I+1 AS PERIOD_NR,
           DATEADD(DAY, 7*V.I, T1.START_DATE) AS START_DATE,
           LEAD(DATEADD(DAY, 7*V.I, T1.START_DATE)) OVER (PARTITION BY PLAN_NR ORDER BY V.I) AS END_DATE
    FROM dbo.TABLE_1 T1
         JOIN cteNum V ON 1000 >= V.I)
SELECT D.PLAN_NR,
       D.PERIOD_NR,
       V.START_DATE
FROM Dates D
     CROSS APPLY (VALUES(START_DATE),(CASE WHEN MONTH(START_DATE) != MONTH(END_DATE) THEN DATEADD(MONTH,DATEDIFF(MONTH,0,END_DATE),0) END)) V(START_DATE)
WHERE V.START_DATE IS NOT NULL
option (maxrecursion 0)
```

[SQL-FIDDLE](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/ed4e1f/2)